# Change password on client with sssd kerberos and ldap

Tags: password-management, ldap, kerberos, passwd

I have an error when I use passwd in ldap user session. 
I get:

```
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
```

I check this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512766/sssd-password-change-not-working-with-ldap-backend) but it didn't help. 
In my `cn=config/olcDatabase={1}mbd.ldif` I have rules:

```
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange,krbPrincipalKey by dn="cn=rootdn,ou=private,ou=tl" write by anonymous auth by self write by * none 
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read 
olcAccess: {2}to * by dn="cn=rootdn,ou=private,ou=tl" write by * read
```

The `getent passwd <ldap user>` works.

Here my configuration files.

sssd.conf file:

```
[sssd]
debug_level = 0xFFF0
config_file_version = 2
services = nss,pam
domains = STAGENFS.FR

[nss]
debug_level = 0xFFF0
filter_users = root
filter_groups = root

[pam]
debug_level = 0xFFF0
offline_credentials_expiration = 1

[domain/STAGENFS.FR]
debug_level = 0xFFF0
ldap_schema = rfc2307
ldap_search_base = ou=tl

id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = krb5
chpass_provider = krb5
access_provider = ldap

ldap_access_order = filter
ldap_access_filter = &(objectClass=posixAccount) (uidNumber=*)

ldap_uri = ldaps://ldap02.stagenfs.fr
ldap_referrals = False
ldap_id_use_start_tls = False
cache_credentials = True
account_cache_expiration = 1
enumerate = True
ldap_default_bind_dn = cn=proxyuser,ou=private,ou=tl
ldap_default_authtok_type = password
ldap_default_authtok = ProxyUser123#
ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem

krb5_realm = STAGENFS.FR
krb5_canonicalize = False
krb5_server = kdc.stagenfs.fr
krb5_kpasswd = kdc.stagenfs.fr
krb5_ccachedir = /home/%u
```

nsswitch file:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat systemd sss
group:          compat systemd sss
shadow:         compat sss
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files sss
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis sss
sudoers:        files sss
```

I have pam_sss.so in pam.d files:

```
# /etc/pam.d/common-account
    account [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore]    pam_sss.so

# /etc/pam.d/common-auth
    auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_sss.so use_first_pass

# /etc/pam.d/common-password
    password    sufficient          pam_sss.so use_authtok

# /etc/pam.d/common-session
    session required    pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/
    session optional            pam_sss.so
```

Do you know if I need sasl configuration for this ? 
If you have any idea, or if you need more informations, don't hesitate ! Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any logs from sssd, or from your Kerberos KDC?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing logs it's hard to help but I try:

I assume you setup MIT Kerberos with OpenLDAP as backend.

Note that changing *krbPrincipalKey* does **not** require write access for the user (self) because the Kerberos key is actually changed by *kadmind* binding to the LDAP server with its service identity.

So you should check whether you have appropiate ACLs in place for *kadmind* and the KDC services. If the ACLs mentioned in your question are all you have then there are definitely missing parts.

You can find the details in the MIT Kerberos docs (based on syntax for OpenLDAP static configuration *slapd.conf*):

[Configuring Kerberos with OpenLDAP back-end](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-current/doc/admin/conf_ldap.html)